Integrating Vue 3 as frontend with Umbraco CMS
I am trying to set up a CMS with Umbraco (v. 14) and then use Vue 3 as the frontend by fetching data through the content delivery API. Since I am new to Umbraco I am not really sure how to set it all up properly. Here is what I want:

I want back office to be able to add a new page. The page should be blank from the beginning and they should be able to add in predefined blocks like "Hero 1", "Product Display" or "Text with Image" etc.
They then pick the blocks they want and fill in the information. They should be able to preview the results before publishing.
In Vue I will then check what pages has been added, loop through each page to find the predefined blocks, and then render the blocks with the stylings I have set in Vue.

So far I have created a new Document Type called "Page Template" which uses a block list as content. I have defined 2 blocks so far, "Hero Block 1" and "Text Image Block". Now I can create a new page under Home with the new Page Template and choose the blocks I want and fill in their respectively information. Lets say I add a "Contact" page.
In Vue I can now run the api request:
async fetchPageData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/umbraco/delivery/api/v2/content`);
    console.log(response.data.items)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching page data:', error);
  }
}

This gives me a lits of "contentType: 'home', name: 'Home'" and then "contentType: 'pageTemplate', name: 'Contact'". I can now loop through the ones of content type pageTemplate, loop through the blocks of each of those pages and then print the content on each page, here is an example code of that:
<div v-for="block in pageData.blocks" :key="block.title">
  <hero-block
    v-if="block.blockType === 'heroBlock'"
    :title="block.title"
    :subtitle="block.subtitle"
    :imageURL="block.imageUrl"
    :ctaButton="block.ctaButton"
  ></hero-block>
  <text-image-block
    v-if="block.blockType === 'textImageBlock'"
    :title="block.title"
    :text="block.text"
    :imageURL="block.imageUrl"
  ></text-image-block>
</div>

Now to the questions:
1. Is this the correct way of doing things in Umbraco when doing headless with Vue (or any other frontend)?
2. If not, can you please let me know the general workflow when doing this?
3. Is there anything I need to think about when it comes to live preview before publishing?

I think in general the setup in Umbraco sounds fine, however the integration on the frontend side is slightly off. There are 2 main ways content is mapped between the backoffice and a frontend application:

using the same structure as in the backoffice where one page corresponds to a URL on the frontend (like in normal websites)
a more indirect approach, where the backoffice contains structure data, but the frontend has an unrelated URL structure (seen this more on SPA type frontends)

This 2 approaches can be combined as well.
From what you have described, you are trying to do the first approach, and for that just calling the /umbraco/delivery/api/v2/content endpoint for all the data from all pages is not ideal as you will alway get a large amount of data that you don't need.
What I would suggest instead is to set up something like what is described in this blog post: https://www.etive-mor.com/blog/a-nextjs-frontend-for-your-umbraco-site/ :

have a routing on the frontend that can handle a catch all route
once a URL is hit, send a request to the by route endpoint

In this way you only get the data needed for that specific page, and as a bonus the URLs/routes can be set on the Umbraco side.
For the preview to work in a headless setup, I would recommend using the Headless Preview package as it can be configured nicely to direct the user to the frontend application.
